# How Do I Turn My Decision Tree Classifier Into A Manual Process?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I am attempting to create a normalization (classification) for certain rock types using scikit-learn. I have my classifier (using the sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier) and am attempting to turn it into some process that you could do implement paper if need be. The classifier uses 11 dimensional data like the following:

```
ROCK NAME |SIO2 |TIO2| AL2O3|   CR2O3|  FEOT|   CAO|    MGO|    MNO|    K2O|    NA2O|   P2O5|  
WEHRLITE    |45.42| 0.17|   2.57|   0.32|   11.3384|    7.54|   31.93|  0.17|   0.01|   0.24|   0.01|
```

I already used tree.export_graphviz to develop a flowchart:
[image]

This is how another type of normalization is laid out which I would like mine to be like:
[link](http://minerva.union.edu/hollochk/c_petrology/norms.htm)
any ideas?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you mean. Can you clarify/correct the phrase "you could do implement paper"?

Comment: Each branch from an internal node refers to an if-else statement on the branching predicates. The leaf nodes are the actual classification

Comment: I want to lay out the classification in such a way that a geologist could understand it

Comment: I don't think there is a premade way to convert a decision tree into a prose description like the page you linked to.  You would have to do that yourself.

Comment: There are no mathematical processes? no formulas? Please excuse my lack of knowledge when it comes to machine learning, but the thing is that I am writing an academic paper and it is hard to explain to Geologists that they should "just download the source code because it works" I want to have some sort of backing or laid out methodology.

Comment: You've hit upon a troubling part of machine learning. While the mathematics behind ML are very strong, it is difficult-bordering-on-impossible to explain the *why* of results from a decision process developed after feeding the machine the data. Your question may reduce to "how to convince a lay-audience that machine learning methods are trustworthy".

Comment: Ah, I noticed you mentioned mathematical processes. ML is very rich with advanced mathematics (well, advanced to me.) Sufficient Google searching will yield the math used in all of ML (other than neural networks which have almost no mathematical foundation.)

Comment: You can look up CART trees (for example in Elements of Statistical Learning, which is a freely available textbook) for the formulation / math. The best way to argue for a model is to show how it performs on the test-set. If your classifier generalizes do new data, this is strong evidence that it "works" (there are also statistical measures for that which might or might not be of interest in your field). Another way might be to look at the tree and see if it makes sense from a domain expert point of view. As long as a tree is small enough, that might work.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html) page seems to discuss how to plot a scikit decision tree.